# <?php and <?= tags in PHP templates

Tags: php, templates

I am learning to build a templating system. In the view folder i have a page that has this code

```
Hello <?= $data["name"]; ?>
```

If i enter this page I see that the code works just with `<?= ?>` tags. I tried `<?php ?>` but it doesn`t work. I thought that the tags have the same functionality. What is the explanation ?

Comment: `<?=` is short open tag syntax for `<?php echo`. That's why it didn't work. As is `<?` is to `<?php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a shortener for

```
<?php echo $data['name']; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, i didn't thought at that. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you happen to know whether some server configurations do not support this notation? I've always considered it bad practice to use `<?=` for that alleged reason.

Comment: @pbond well i think <? is bad practice because of issues with configuration and xml compatibility, but <?= should be ok

Comment: You can see here what users says about this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

Comment: Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available

Comment: Just clarifying @Danijel's comment: before 5.4.0, disabling short tags would disable both `<?` and `<?=`. As of 5.4.0, disabling short tags just disables `<?`. There is no option to disable `<?='